# getting hold of a list from parent web

Tags: list

Just want to make sure that the following syntax will work. The look-up list is on the parent list.

```
SPList lookupList = web.ParentWeb.GetList("States");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax looks fine, of course there are a lot of assumptions here:

- you are not already at the top-level web
- the list exists on the parent
- the current user has permissions to the list on the parent web

If you are fine with all those assumptions, it looks right.

Comment: All of your assumptions are correct. Cool. I will implement it accordingly. Thanks